# How can I make a BaseCustomLayer Draw() fire more often?

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

I'm experimenting with the idea of replacing my dynamic display moving graphics with the static (DynamicDisplayEnabled = false) moving graphics.

```
public class CustomLayer : BaseCustomLayer
{
        public override void Draw(esriDrawPhase drawPhase, IDisplay Display, ITrackCancel trackCancel)
        {
            int hdc = Display.hDC;
            IntPtr p = new IntPtr(hdc);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(p);
            Image newImage = Image.FromFile(carImage);
            System.Drawing.Point ulCorner = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner);
        }
}
```

This code draws the image, but it only invokes draw once, unless I move the map with the pan tool or change the scale.   How can I make the Draw function fire multiple times a second?

Comment: Not an answer but just something you might want to try if the screen just isn't updating as you expect: call IScreenDisplay.UpdateWindow to force the window to respond to any pending WM_PAINT messages. Things weren't drawing in the expected order for me without a call to that after IActiveView.Refresh but before my StartDrawing/EndDrawing section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but when I was working on a project for vehicle tracking I think we used a timer in conjunction with Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher to force a refresh.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599902/c-how-to-force-calling-a-method-from-the-main-thread-by-signaling-in-some-way/4599945#4599945) on using CurrentDispatcher.

I think we checked to make sure [IViewRefresh](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000rt6000000).Drawing was false before calling refresh, but I think there were issues with that.